# How do I stop from the team-score resetting after each loops?

Tags: java, loops

```
 //Author: Asim
//Date: 10th November 2016
//Description: This program is used to ask the user what theyre favourite music genre is. The user receives a score which count towards a team score. 

    import java.util.Scanner; //Importing the scanner 
    import java.util.Random;  //Importing the dice

    public class MiniProject6{

//Main method   

        public static void main(String[]p){
        for(int counter=1; counter<=4; counter++){
        Info i1 = new Info();
            i1 = setQuestion(i1, "What is the best music genre?"); //Here are the vales which are being set for Question and CorrectAnswer
            System.out.print(getQuestion(i1));
            i1 = setCorrectanswer(i1, "Drill");

        String ans = answer();
        int [] pScore = new int[2];
        boolean finish;
        finish = checker(ans, getCorrectanswer(i1), pScore); //Cross references the users input with the CorrectAnswer
        }
    }
//End main

//Answer method returns the value the user types

    public static String answer()
    {
        Scanner asim = new Scanner(System.in);
        String music;
        music = asim.nextLine();

        return music;
    }
//End answer
//Checker method is used to see if the users answer is the same as the record correct answer    

       public static boolean checker(String ans, String Correctanswer, int pScore[]){       

        boolean finish;
        if (ans.equals(Correctanswer)){ 
            print("Congrats, " + Correctanswer + " is the correct answer!");        
                    finish = true;
            if (finish == true){
                int score = dice(); 

                    print("The score is " + score);
                if (score<6){               
                    print("Lets add another 3 onto the score. ");
                    pScore[0] = score+3;
                        print("Total score is: " + pScore[0]);  
                        pScore[1] = pScore[1] + pScore[0];
                }
                else if (score>5){ 
                    print("Lets add another 6 onto the score. ");   
                    pScore[0] = score+6;
                        print("Total score is: " + pScore[0]);
                        pScore[1] = pScore[1] + pScore[0];
                }
            }    
                        System.out.println(finish);
                        System.out.println("Currently the teamscore is " + pScore[1]);

        }
            else{
                print("The correct answer is " + Correctanswer + ", unfortunately you got it wrong");
                finish = false;     
                System.out.println(finish);
            }
            return finish;          
    }
//End Checker   

//Dice method is used to create the dice

    public static int dice(){       
        Random Dice = new Random();
        int answer = Dice.nextInt(6) + 1;

        return answer;
    }
//End dice
```

Comment: Use IDE to debug the code

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to aggregate your score you need to check the scope of your score variable/create a score variable that is not contained within the for loop. if the variable is initialized within the for loop then every iteration will reset the variable. Simply move the variable instantiation outside of the loop and reference it inside the loop. Then your score will not be reset.

Comment: How do i do that without having a global variable?

Comment: The way you are doing it right now is not a great way to do it. From my understanding you are creating an array of 2 int values and adding them together in your check method. However, this is as simple as moving the `        int [] pScore = new int[2];` out of the for loop and outside of the main method.

Comment: Because what you are doing through each iteration is creating a completely new Array! This erases whatever value you had in your old array meaning that you get no saved information. Again it is better to use a global variable (maybe call it `total`) and aggregate your score there by adding on to it, but the code organization is up to you.